# Package cannot find nav_msgs even though its listed as a dependency?

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to run a ROS node for the ax2550 motor controller, found here:

https://github.com/wjwwood/ax2550

However, when I try to compile with catkin_make, I get the following error:

CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:255 (message):
Messages depends on unknown pkg: nav_msgs (Missing find_package(nav_msgs?))
Call Stack (most recent call first):
ax2550/CMakeLists.txt:22 (generate_messages)

Everything I can find about this error online simply indicates that I need to specify nav_msgs as a dependency to my package, but it's already there:

<build_depend>nav_msgs</build_depend>
<run_depend>nav_msgs</run_depend>

Any ideas as to what could br going wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186697/package-cannot-find-nav_msgs-even-though-its-listed-as-a-dependency?/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-07-16**:
Make sure that nav_msgs is installed, the following command should show the path to nav_msgs: rospack find nav_msgs

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-07-16**:
It is installed, and entering that command returns the correct path: /opt/ros/hydro/share/nav_msgs.  Although maybe its possible that the node isn't looking for nav_msgs there--I don't know hot tell from the code or the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-common-msgs

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2014-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-07-16**:
Tried that but it said it installed nothing new.  Nav_msgs is already installed.

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-07-16**:
This sounds like its an environment issue. Could you install ros-hydro-common-msgs from source and try recompiling?  (with the ax550 and the nav_msgs in the same src directory).

As well, please sudo rm -rf devel build inside your catkin_ws.

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-07-16**:
Reinstalling it from source in the same src directory did the trick.  For anyone else with this problem,

```
git clone https://github.com/ros/common_msgs
```

And then catkin_make again.  Thanks!

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-07-16**:
It might have been only a matter of rebuilding the catking_ws. I would try to remove the source code for common_msgs that you just installed and rm -rf devel build inside your catking_ws, then catkin_make again and see what happens.

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-07-18**:
Tried that, but got the same error again; "messages depends on unknown package: nav_msgs"

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-07-19**:
O_O Thanks for trying and posting back the result